# Postsharp Aspect with Async methods

Tags: postsharp

I'm using Trial Ultimate version of PostSharp 4.0 but this doesn't work for me. Can you please check my code and advise. The error doesn't gets logged. And if i put the breakpoint doesn't hit onException method

This is code that I've written for Error handling Aspect

```
[Serializable] 
public class MyMethodAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public MyMethodAspectAttribute()
    {
        this.ApplyToStateMachine = true;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.Write("Method Entry");
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.Write(args.Exception.Message);
        args.ReturnValue = null;
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}
```

This is class where I've implemented this aspect

```
public class ErrorMethods
{
    [MyMethodAspect]
    public Task<int> Calculate(int i, int j)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => i / j);
        return task;
    }
}
```

This is how I've used this method

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new ErrorMethods();

        var result = await obj.Calculate(1, 0);

        if (null  == result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Calculate` method in your example is not an async method, so setting `ApplyToStateMachine` aspect's property doesn't have effect on this method. The exception is thrown when a newly created task executes in the background and the aspect has no chance of catching it.

If you change your `Calculate` method to async method, then the async state machine execution can be intercepted by the aspect and `OnException` handler is invoked upon exception.

Note, however that setting the `ReturnValue` and `FlowBehavior` does not alter the flow of the state machine, so the exception will not be swallowed.

```
public class ErrorMethods
{
    [MyMethodAspect]
    public async Task<int> Calculate( int i, int j )
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew( () => i / j );
    }
}
```

Comment: Bummer ... Is there some way to swallow the exception and return null to the actual error occurring method. Please suggest this can be major show stopper in purchasing such a awesome product.